# How can I stop my submenu from disappearing while hovering between spaced submenu items?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS menu with a submenu, and each submenu list item has a 1px space between them. The problem mostly occurs in IE, but unless you move your cursor very quickly, the submenu will disappear while hovering between the two submenu items (due to the 1px space). How do I stop this from happening while keeping the 1px spaces?

```
<nav id="menu" class="sixteen columns">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">drop 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">drop 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">drop 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 
    </ul>
</nav>

#menu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
ul#nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1px 0;
    width: auto;
}
/* start first level nav items */
ul#nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 4px;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}
ul#nav li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px 9px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
ul#nav li.current a, ul#nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}       

ul#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10em;
    left: -999em;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul#nav li ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1px 0;
}
ul#nav li ul li a, 
ul#nav li.current ul li a {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #fff;
}
ul#nav li ul li a:hover, 
ul#nav li.current ul li a:hover {   
    background-color: #FA891C;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: your submenu does not show with the current setup => http://jsfiddle.net/Q36R7/

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Probably he use some JS and yes, this doesn't work. Please post your Javascript code (if you are using some) to help you with the menus. I had it clear when saw `left: -999em`

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX he shouldn't though! he could very easily use CSS to make the submenu work. :)

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Yea, but as you see, it doesnt work xD

Comment: Go back to 2011 and follow the tutorial http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the 1px margin and add a 1px spacer that is part of the hover element.

```
ul#nav li ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1px 0;   /* change to margin:0px;*/
}
```

And...

```
ul#nav li.current ul li a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;   /*Add this*/
    padding: 0px;                           /*And this*/

    width: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

and add this css

```
.subMenu1
{
    margin-left:10px; /* adjust as needed */
}
```

and wrap your submenu items in a div like this:

```
<li><a href="#"><div class="subMenu1">drop 1</div></a></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BZkfy/

Comment: Can you expand on this please? What do you mean a 1px spacer?

Comment: expanded :) @Christopher - exactly

Comment: my original explanation didn't quite do it - please look again above

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery hoverIntent plugin to add a delay that will allow users to keep focus on your menus.

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

E.G.

```
    $('.main-nav > ul > li').hoverIntent({
        timeout: 300,
        over: function () {
            $(this).addClass('hover')
        },
        timeout: 300,
        out: function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover')
        }
    });
```

Comment: Answers with links should have examples